# Heroku/devise - Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, actionmailer

I am trying to push my app on heroku. I am still in dev.
I use devise with the confirmable module.

When I try to add a user with the heroku console I got this error:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]
```

in test and dev environment i have the following line:

## environments/development.rb and environments/test.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

I don't have set up something in the production environment.

I've tried to push with

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mywebsitename.com' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'heroku.mywebsitename.com' }
```

but it doesn't work too..

I see on the web that it could be related to ActionMailer but I don't know what I have to configure.
Many thanks for your idea!

## EDITED:

Hi,

In order to not make my app crashes when I push on heroku I put this in my env/test.rb and my env/dev.rb (not in env.rb I think it is because it's a rails 3 app)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' }
```

But when I tried to create a user in the heroku console:

```
User.create(:username => "test", :email => "test@test.com", :password => "test1234", :password_confirmation => "test1234", :confirmed_at => "2010-11-03 14:11:15.520128")
```

here are errors I got:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]
/home/slugs/.../mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:473:in `url_for'
/home/slugs/.../mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:132:in `url_for'
/home/slugs/.../mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
/home/slugs/.../mnt/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:195:in `user_confirmation_url'
```

## EDITED (2)

When I type heroku logs on console I got this ==> production.log <== So I think when one deploys on heroku it's already in production.

I configure the env/prod.rb like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' }
```

and now I have this as error when I try to create a User:

```
Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT: Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2)
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `initialize'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `open'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
```

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You need to add this to your `environment.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
```

Make sure you change `host` to your production url and keep it localhost for development. This is for the mailer, it needs a default email to send out notices such as confirmations etc...

---

You should check the logs on the heroku server `heroku logs` run that from the console and it will tell you the exact error.

When you push to heroku you need to configure the `environment.rb` file with the heroku subdomain:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' }
```

---

Depending upon version, this should go in `production.rb`, not `environment.rb`.

Comment: Hi sam! I am sorry but i didn't get it. I just add the line config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
in my env.rb but my rails 3 app crashes on heroku. Did I have to put something on the env/prod.rb too? (sorry my english is so so-so..)

Comment: Also ,did I have to put my rails app in production mode? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam, I added also some info in the body of my question. Your answer helps but I can't still register a user via heroku console. I would be pleased if you can tell me what you thinks on this! Thanks!

Comment: `:host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' ` this should be your domain. For example, if your domain is yahoo.com, then it should be `yahoo.heroku.com` or if you already setup custom domains it will just be your url `yahoo.com`

Comment: Thanks Sam, I find the solution. The fact is that I didn't have the sendgrid addon and my smtp hasn't configured. Many thanks for all your backup!

Comment: lol. No problem, now you can get devise going on all you apps :)

Comment: Isn't it going to be `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.herokuapp.com'`, as opposed to just `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com'` ?

Comment: You should set exact address to your app: if it is available at `yourapp.herokuapp.com`, just set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'yourapp.herokuapp.com' }`, otherwise devise will generate incorrect link ex. in confirmation email.

Answer (score 41):

Ok,

First you have to install the sendgrid gem with this command line:

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid:free
```

Then you just have to configure your env/dev.rb and env/prod.rb like this:

env/dev.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

env/prod.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' }
```

Push on git and heroku. It should work..

Comment: I get this error when I reference config.action_mailer in production.rb:

/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/
rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails:
:Application::Configuration:0x0000000241f760> (NoMethodError)

Comment: I am not sure I can help here... Did you reference it inside the block? (Website::Application.configure do ... config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'yourapp.heroku.com' } ... end)

Comment: now the sendgrid command is heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter (view usage details at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid)

Answer (score 24):

Codeglot's anwser above does the job, but we wanted something a bit more flexible, so we did this:

On Heroku, we run multiple Production environments for staging and testing, so we need a flexible solution for the production.rb environment file.

In production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['MAILER_URL'] }
```

Then set the MAILER_URL environment variable for your app like so

```
heroku config:set MAILER_URL=my-awesome-app.herokuapp.com --app my-awesome-app
```

Answer (score 18):

**If you're running on *Cedar*:**

1. run `heroku addons:add sendgrid:free` from your console.
2. Add the following lines to `config/environments/production.rb` in your app.

.

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com'
  }

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE.COM' }
```

Answer (score 14):

I had to do a number of things to get it to work in the **production** environment: 
Inside of my `production.rb` file (/config/environments/production.rb) I added the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'myappsname.herokuapp.com'
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

This is with **Rails 4** and **Devise 3**

Comment: This structure of the `default_url_options` caused an error which made my precompiling assets fail, just fyi.  When I changed it back to ` = { host: 'myappsname.herokuapp.com' }` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The working one after so many research,

1. Don't forget to add default **from: mail** address in your **ApplicationMailer (application_mailer.rb)** as,

   ```
   class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
     default from: 'yourmail@gmail.com'
     layout 'mailer'
   end
   ```
2. Add the below configuration in your **production.rb**.

   ```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = 
     { :host => 'yourapp.herokuapp.com' }
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
     port:                 587,
     domain:               'heroku.com',
     user_name:            'yourmail@gmail.com',
     password:             'yourgmailpassword',
     authentication:       'login',
     enable_starttls_auto: true
   }
   ```
3. Enable IMAP from your Gmail settings in **Forwarding IMAP/POP** tab.
4. **Allow less secure apps: ON** from https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

You're now good to go. :)