# Named route in mailer template raises missing :host option even though default host is configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer, spree

Using named routes in any of my application's mailers is raising this error:

```
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

This isn't happening all the time and I can't reproduce locally in either development or production mode.

If I open a console in production, I can confirm that the default host is configured:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
 => {:host=>"thehost.com"} 
Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
 => {:host=>"thehost.com"} 
Spree::Core::Engine.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
 => {:host=>"thehost.com"}
```

All the named routes are being called through Spree's routing proxy:

```
<%= spree.my_route_url %>
```

I have the following in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "thehost.com" }
```

This may be redundant since Spree also sets it from the :site_url preference (which I have configured correctly)

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = Spree::Config[:site_url]
```

(from mail_settings.rb)

Spree is version 1-0-stable
Rails 3.1.3
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I was able to confirm that when this error happens, default_url_options is: {"host"=>""}. Seems that restarting the processes, or in a console that value gets set correctly.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I have a similar problem...

Comment: Ok, I got it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114835/heroku-devise-missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-host-parameter-or-set-d