# Missing host to link to action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

i am using rails and devise and i am trying to send emails but i get the following error in production and test eviroments, in development all works fine:

ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
     # ./app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_reset_password_instructions_html_erb___200197999_97517150'

My development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

test.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mydomain.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

reset_password_instructions.html.erb

```
<p>Hello, <%= @resource.full_name %>!</p>

<p>You have request a new passord</p>

    <p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token), class: 'btn btn-info' %></p>
    <p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
    <p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402816/1759437, setting the default_url_options on application_controller.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if it was a typo or not, but looks like the host definition for test and production is not set properly.

test.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://loclahost:3000" }
```

production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http:/mydomain.com" }
```

It should work once they are set properly. For example:

test.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mydomain.com" }
```

Comment: Hi, i changed my lines with yours but still have the same error it seems like there is a variable that it cant find , (i will edit my question and correct the urls)

Comment: Was the server restarted? Also, can you describe where is the application deployed on production?

Comment: Yes i restart the server, the application is deployed on heroku

Comment: I found an intializer/setup_mailer.rb that containse the following line: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = ENV["DEFAULT_HOST"] that maybe override the code in production.rb in fact the env variable DEFAULT_HOST was not set on heroku and after setting it in procuction all works fine. Still having the same issue in the test enviroment by the way.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I added the following with the correct value to each environment file:

*test.rb* / *development.rb* / *production.rb*

**Devise 3.2.x**

**Rails 4.1.x**

Thanks to [maudulus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208572/737275)

```
# Default Mailer Host
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'domain.com'
```

***Note do not load the value from an ENV variable or it will throw the error**.

Comment: Thanks for adding this note. I was loading value from Figaro and couldn't figured out why it was not working !