# ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer, production

My ruby on rails action mailer runs all good in development environment, but in production environment, it keeps throw:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

My development config is

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => xxx,
  :address        => 'smtp.example.org',
  :user_name      => 'xxx@example.com',
  :password       => 'xxxxxxxx',
  :domain         => 'xxxxxx.example',
  :authentication => :plain,
}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

My production config is

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => 587,
  :address        => 'smtp.example.org',
  :user_name      => 'xxx@example.com',
  :password       => 'xxxxxx',
  :domain         => 'example.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
```

My other environments are:

```
ruby 2.1.1
rails 4.0.3
sidekiq
devise
devise-async
```

I have tried:

1. Add the following in a initializer file

   ```
   ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "example.com"
   ```
2. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219803)

Neither of them works.

Comment: This is strange. I just got the same error and adding config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://example.com" } to my application.rb resolved the issue... Are you sure your config is picked up correctly?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In the end I added the following with the correct value to each environment file:

`test.rb` / `development.rb` / `production.rb`

**Devise 3.2.x - 4.x.x**

**Rails 4.1.x**  &&  **Rails 4.2.x** &&  **Rails 5.x.x**

Thanks to [maudulus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208572/737275)

```
# Default Mailer Host
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'domain.example'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I was able to load from an ENV variable.  Rails 4.1.7.

Comment: Awesome I'm glad that has been updated. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Finally a solution that works, this question is a perfect example where most results on Stackoverflow are simply outdated or just bad.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me for Rails 5.0.0 and Devise 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks ! The only solution that worked in my case (Rails 5.0) !

Comment: I don't get what the problem is at heart? What is a missing host? Why doesn't it infer the host?

Comment: Finally, a solution that helped me that wasn't setting config.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }

Answer (score 4):

Try restarting the server. Even in Rails 4.1 the config is not reparsed without a restart.

Comment: Alongside this, if you're triggering mail actions from the console, you might need to restart the console too.