# ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I have built a module in Solidus and ruby on rails and now I try to create tests.

I am trying to create some integration tests and I have this error:

**E
Error:
PrescriptionPhotosTest#test_/prescription_photos_post_endpoint_throws_an_error_when_wrong_params:
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
    test/integration/prescription_photos_test.rb:6:in `block in '**

I read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131936/missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-the-host-parameter-for-rails-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288951/actionviewtemplateerror-missing-host-to-link-to-please-provide-the-host-p), but it doesn't make any difference.

My code is returning this error on this line:

> @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

Here is the code from my files.

**prescription_photos_rest.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PrescriptionPhotosTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    Spree::Auth::Config[:confirmable] = false
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  def authenticated_header
    token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: @user.id }).token
    {
        'Authorization': "Bearer #{token}"
    }
  end

  test '/prescription_photos post endpoint throws an error when wrong params' do
     post '/api/prescription_photos', headers: authenticated_header, params: {
       something: {
           is: 'wrong'
       }
     }

    json = JSON.parse(body)

     assert_response 422
     assert json.has_key? 'exception'
     assert_equal 'param is missing or the value is empty: prescription', json['exception']
  end
end
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: Spree::User do
    email 'test@test.nl'
    password 'test123'
    password_confirmation 'test123'
  end
end
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

**test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=3600'
  }

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Add the host parameter
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost' }

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

After running rake test:integration I got the error mentioned above.

I did a lot of googleing and I tried to fix this problem in the past 2 days, but I had no luck.

Comment: So I'm assuming you tried with using a default_url_options in the test.rb environment config and that it didn't solve it. Have you tried with   `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`

Comment: It is already there. I updated the question and I added also the code from test.rb @MicaelNussbaumer

Comment: You shouldn't even need `.default_url_options` I think. But you have it set in two different places, can you remove the second one where you're not specifying the `:port`?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer, I did and I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I would say to remove the host configuration in `test.rb`, since it's not the cause. I have never used Spree so not sure if it's that that triggers the email sending on user creation? Perhaps you should look into that?

Comment: 'Spree::Auth::Config[:confirmable] = false' ,this line of code from `prescription_photos_rest.rb` was overwritten buy a env value.  @MicaelNussbaumer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Spree::Auth::Config[:confirmable] = false
```

This line of code from `prescription_photos_rest.rb` was overwritten buy a env value.